# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, api, google-maps

hello 
I have made application in Google Api level 7 and is running normally in Emulator with Google API 7.I am confuse that if i run this application in Api level 7 without Google API then what result i found? is application run normally? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google APIs include maps.jar that is a required library to show maps related features. These are also available on devices but when you switch to a non google (only Android) API, this will call a missing shared library error.

Either drop the use of any maps features or run only using Google API.

Comment: can we install maps features in API without map features?@azharb

Comment: In the past, I've tried to copy the maps.jar out of the Google-Android Library and tried to manually add it to my library list but that didn't work. So, my leaning would be to say No. (I think that's what you were asking about, right?)

Comment: But my application is based on Google map and i want to run my application in every device With 2.1 then how can i do that.please help me.

Comment: There are devices without Google Maps installed on them. GM is Google's property and they don't share it with non approved devices. So, your only option is to restrict your app to ONLY devices that have google maps installed. Which means the above mentioned error will pop up when you try to do otherwise.

Comment: ok so my application's scope is limited to only for those devices that supports Google Map am i right?